# Delete last 5 characters in a string

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column with suburb names and postcodes - eg - MARLEY HEIGHTS 2067. I want to remove the last 5 characters and get the suburb name only. i.e., MARLEY HEIGHTS as the result. How can I do that in big query ?

I tried Rtrim(column,' ') as suburb, but this did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SUBSTR(string, 1, LENGTH(string) - 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option to consider

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(string, '.{5}$', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the postcode is numeric, you can express it in a cleaner way for my taste, by saying: "remove the blank followed by a bunch of digits at the end" in a `REGEXP_REPLACE()` call.

```
WITH
indata(s) AS (
  SELECT 'MARLEY HEIGHTS 2067'
)
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(s,' \d+$','') AS without_postcode
-- replace space, then digits (`\d`), one or more times (`+`), then end of line (`$`)
-- with nothing (`''`)
FROM indata;
-- out  without_postcode 
-- out ------------------
-- out  MARLEY HEIGHTS
```

Regular expression functions are indeed powerful ....

Answer (score 0):

one more way using `rtrim` & `right` functions could help remove the last 5 characters

```
WITH
indata AS (
  SELECT 'MARLEY HEIGHTS 2067' as text
)
select RTRIM(text, right(text, 5)) from indata
```